# How do I safely run a model action from a user link_to click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The overview of what i'm trying to do is resend an "activate account" email to a user upon their request. Basically, a user signs up and is sent an activation email, which works perfectly. Here's the code in the user model that sends the activation email upon creating a temporary user:

```
  def deliver_activation(invitation = nil)
    Mailer.activation(self, invitation).deliver
  end
```

What I want to be able to do is offer a way for the user to click a link to resend the activation if they lost it or never received it for whatever reason. If the user tries to login without having activated first, a page on my site tells them that they have not activated yet. I would like to offer them a link to click to resend that activation email like so:

```
<%= link_to "click here to resend" %>
```

I'm just not sure what is a safe/optimal way of doing this. If it's done via a POST with the user_id to send the email to, it is open to people sending all my users an activation link. How do I allow the user to resend themselves the email? I assume I have to add something to one of my controllers to trigger that deliver_activation action in my model...but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the current user ID in a session variable then you could just use a simple controller GET action with a redirect to send the email, a la:

```
def deliver_activation(invitation = nil)
  user = @current_user
  Mailer.activation(user, invitation).deliver
  redirect_to "wherever you want to send them to"
end
```

That way, only a user logged in can send an activation email to themselves. Does that make sense?

Hope this helps

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protected

  helper_method :current_user 

  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

end
```

Comment: Well, the problem is the user doesn't create their password until they activate. They enter their email address and are sent the initial activation code. When they activate, they are prompted for some more info and to create a password. So, they are never logged in, but we have their email address stored and waiting for them.

Comment: I still think you should be able to create a session that's stored with their user ID (aren't they created in the database when they sign up?)

Comment: I think you are right. The problem is I don't have the @user (what I use as @current_user) in my sessions_controller#deliver_activation once I go to call that action. I have it in the page with the link_to to the deliver_activation action, but not when I actually need it. I'm not sure how to pass user without exposing the app to someone sending out activation links to all my users.

Comment: You should be able to write a ApplicationController protected action that you can use. I'll post how in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the user sign in using the login/pwd they have created and then maintain a 'status' field in your database indicating whether or not this user has activated his/her account. If not, show a link on the site:

"Please activate your account via the email we had sent to you, If you have lost it click here to Resend Activation Code".